# Jersey HK2 Dependency Injection doesn't work after update to v2.27

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs, hk2

I have a project using Jersey v2.25.1. I was using Jersey's inbuilt HK2 injection to perform dependency injection, and everything worked fine. Fast forward to now, I decided to update to Jersey v2.27.

When I ran my project, I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found
```

After some googling, I found that I needed to add the `jersey-hk2` dependency. Doing so made me get the following exception:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=<MyClass>,parent=<MyClass>,qualifiers={},position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1044705957)
```

Upon reverting all my dependencies to Jersey v2.25.1, everything works fine. What do I need to do to fix these errors, so I can use Jersey v2.27?

Edit:
I don't use Maven so I can't really post a `pom.xml`, but tommorow I will put together an MVCE with the exact dependencies I have, and a basic example of Dependency Injection.

Comment: Please show your code for better help. It is not possible to for us to figure out what's going on with out it. Try providing a [MCVE].

Comment: @PaulSamsotha This isn't really a code problem, more of a config problem. I just need to figure out what configuration I need (extra dependencies, maybe) to make this run. I will post an MVCE tommorow, although it will probably be difficult as I don't use Maven (that's a different story altogether)

Comment: It _is_ a code problem because there are breaking changes related to dependency injection starting from version 2.26.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Okay, I will post an MVCE as soon as I can. Thanks

Comment: @PaulSamsotha For now, here is my current code - my [abstract binder - line 58](https://github.com/ArjMart/API/blob/d3ef41a858cf22a0c58da94cf5fdb42c3fe5313b/src/com/arjvik/arjmart/api/Hk2Feature.java#L58) and my [injection point - line 30](https://github.com/ArjMart/API/blob/d3ef41a858cf22a0c58da94cf5fdb42c3fe5313b/src/com/arjvik/arjmart/api/ETagFilter.java#L30). This shows how I bind one single interface and implementation, then inject it into a filter.

Comment: Try to change your `AbstractBinder` import. There are two, a Jersey one and an HK2 one. Try to use the Jersey one.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thank you so much!! If you mark that as an answer, I would happily accept it! --FYI, the API is a bit different, for example the `bindFactory` method now requires a `java.util.function.Supplier<T>` instead of the old HK2 `Factory<T>`

Comment: You can go ahead and answer your own question. Just post what changes you made. I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer by [Paul Samsotha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/paul-samsotha) in a comment:

> Try to change your AbstractBinder import. There are two, a Jersey one and an HK2 one. Try to use the Jersey one.

Basically, I needed to change the AbstractBinder class I implemented from

```
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder
```

to

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder
```

The difference is that Jersey decoupled HK2 from it's internal DI mechanism in version 2.26, and thus, I needed to use the new AbstractBinder import, which comes directly from Jersey, and not HK2.

There are a few API differences: for instance, instead of a `Factory<T>`, `bindFactory()` takes a `java.util.function.Supplier<T>`.