# REST JAX-RS Custom Context Provider not working

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using glassfish Jersey JAX-RS on Java 11 and Tomcat 9 server. I  upgraded my Jersey version to 2.27 recently after @Context object is coming null in my application. This object belongs to a 3rd party API.

The version of Jersey in the 3rd party API, having the context element, is 1.19 and also, it belongs to com.sun package and not the one I am using which is org.glassfish. 
My called Rest method looks like:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Pageable<Role> getRoles(@Context final Search search) throws ServerException {

    return new Pageable<>(identityManagementService.getRoles(), search);
}
```

which calls following :

```
public Pageable(final List<T> list, final Search search) {
    this.count = list.size();
    this.data = list;
    if (search.getLimiter() != null && search.getLimiter().getCount() != 0) {
        this.data = list.stream()
               .skip(search.getLimiter().getOffset())
                .limit(search.getLimiter().getCount())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

} 
}

3rd party Pom.xml has following entry :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I have following entry in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
```

The Search object is coming null at the run-time, causing my application to fail. Is there any compatibility issue between the two jersey versions or am I missing something. Is anyone already using Jersey JAX-RS 2.27 and Java 11 together ?

Comment: @cassio-mazzochi-molin could you help

Comment: Why @Context  is need here?.Could you please share your request.May be u need to add @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).

Comment: @Prasobh.K It is a custom context object, it is like bean injection in spring. I am using this Search context for filtering of the request as you can see in the above code's Pageable method. As far as request is concerned it is a simple get request with queryparams which are mapped to Search object. The get uri is :
https://localhost:8080/App/rest/api/admin/roles?max=20&off=0

Comment: Context is used to inject container managed objects.Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719533/understanding-rest-apis-what-are-context-and-context.  If you have to get value in Search object, u have to sent corresponding JSON in the request.

Comment: @Prasobh.K yes thats true, but you can have your custom context providers as well. You may refer to this https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/rest-custom-context-providers. I am sending two parameters as query params  in request which are properties of Search object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. I was referring to AbstractBinder of HK2 package after updating my Jersey to 2.27. The new version on Jersey Jax-RS got decoupled from HK2. Importing org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder and implementing corresponding overridden methods solved the issue.
The answer posted here [Jersey HK2 Dependency Injection doesn't work after update to v2.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217120/jersey-hk2-dependency-injection-doesnt-work-after-update-to-v2-27) helped me in reolving the issue.

Thanks